# "You can only undo a comment vote in the first 60 seconds": is this an approach to handling gaming of upvotes

Tags: discussion, comment-votes

I had upvoted a comment here:

[Define return value in Spark Scala UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44291876/define-return-value-in-spark-scala-udf)

Then after reading several answers I discovered the asker (who is an experienced SOF user) - had *answered their own question*.  But .. *their* answer ends up at the bottom since it did not have any upvotes.

So - having realized now that the comment were likely out of date - and certainly inaccurate - I went to cancel the upvote.  This whole thing did not last two minutes..

But here we are:

[image]

This just *must* be due to some kind of past experiences with users gaming something or other.  But .. well .. *thanks* for imposing this restriction on all users ..

Is there not any other/(/better) way to deal with the occasional gaming going on.. ?

Comment: I dont see how this has to do with gaming.. comment votes dont give any rep at all

Comment: I'm trying to give benefit of the doubt - since other restrictions that make little sense (without more context) are attributed to preventing gaming.

Comment: I don't understand why there are more restrictions on undoing comment upvotes than votes on questions and answers. Votes on questions and answers are more important, so it should be the other way around.

Comment: Downvoters please explain a bit . This is a surprising behavior.

Comment: I didn't vote on your question.. just observed that the restriction being because of gaming is unlikely

Comment: Suraj:  Fair enough: thanks.

Comment: @rene  This is a general question -  not being able to change votes in such a tiny window of time.   As to the particulars - I prefer not to involve moderators except under more serious conditions.

Comment: It is ok to attach a different weight on that condition - but in any case this question is about the 60 seconds restriction rather than the content of the comment itself.

Comment: @rene "Comments are mostly noise, let's not put too much functionality into it." I can't tell you how many times I saw a comment improve an answer *significantly*. I sometimes feel alienated by the "comments are noise" concept. Why even have comments then?

Comment: @rene  Have you never found the comments helpful to you on solving real world problems?  They have for me  low hundreds of times. As the4kman says the comments are often critical for clarifying/improving the answers.  It is pretty shocking to hear this concept of dropping comments.

Comment: "Horrible".  "superior".  You're pretty confident in your opinion on this versus other approaches.  You have a decent amount of answers (688) but very few questions (28): you might try to respect/realize that those of us making a more balanced questions/answers put more weight on aspects of the site different from those you do.

Comment: comments should be used to get more clarification from posts and to add further information, then the poster should in reality edit that information into the post then the comment should be deleted, therefore noise

Answer (score 4):

You have the history the wrong way around.  Originally, comment upvotes were permanent, and there has never been any support for reversing comments after an extended period of time.  The Stack Exchange folks decided to allow 60 second un-upvoting [to correct misclicks only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129032/275243).  They specifically *don't want to support your use case* of changing your mind after the fact.

Now let's look at the rationale.  Actually, no rationale was given, so let's extrapolate.  The purpose of comments is to suggest improvements and discuss clarifications on questions and answers.  They are not places where answers or extended discussion are supposed to live, nor are they intended to be at all subjective.  Ideally, it should be obvious whether a comment is good or bad.  Furthermore, "bad" comments are supposed to be flagged and removed; that's why there's no downvote button.

For this specific case, you can flag the comment as obsolete, and a moderator will delete it.  Un-upvoting it would just leave a trap for the next person who comes along.